# How to upload a file from the web onto Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a link to a file (like so: http://example.com/tmp/database.csv). I want to upload it directly into S3, instead of downloading it on my computer first (and then uploading). Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file will have to move through some application you write. Amazon S3 does not have any mechanism to execute code or pull files, so the only way to do this is to send it directly from the server where the file is hosted or from another server.